# This interleave code wont work

Tags: python, algorithm

Trying to make an interleave but am having trouble as I am a beginner.
It's suppose to interleave the sets of integers when they are tested but I just keep getting an error message saying "Index out of range".

```
def interleave(nums):
    new_nums = []
    index = 0
    if len(nums) == 0:
        return new_nums
    for j in range(len(nums)):
        for i in range(len(nums[0])):
            new_nums.append(nums[j][index])
            index += 1
    return new_nums
```

and it is tested with these values:

```
print("Testing interleave() for nums = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]: " + str(
    interleave([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])))
```

The expected result is :

```
[1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 8, 3, 6, 9]
```

When tested with these two values:

```
print("Testing interleave() for nums = [[0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]]: " + str(
    interleave([[0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]])))  
print("Testing interleave() for nums = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 0]]: " + str(
    interleave([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 0]])))
```

The expected results should be:

```
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1] 
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8, 0]
```

But I get an IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Please show the error message.

Comment: And what is expected result?

Comment: ok I updated the post with the error message and the expected result

Comment: OK. Is it guaranteed that all sublists have the same length?

Comment: No it is not guaranteed that all the sublists have the same length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that `index` is never reset, so you get a maximum value of `index` which is the amount of tuples you have.

Maybe you'd find it easier if you'd go about it the other way round, first you loop over the single tuple elements, and then over the list of tuples. That way you could also get rid of `index`:

```
def interleave(nums):
    new_nums = []
    if len(nums) == 0:
        return new_nums
    for j in range(len(nums[0])):
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            new_nums.append(nums[i][j])
    return new_nums

print("Testing interleave() for nums = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]: " + str(
    interleave([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])))
```

Comment: I tested it with more values and I updated the original post about how I still get an IndexError with different values, maybe because one of the sublists is a different length

Comment: Yes, if one of the sublists is a different length, it will give an `IndexError`. You need to decide if it makes sense to have an interleave with different lengths, and how to behave in that case. Do you want to drop the extra values? Add `0`s so that they all have the same length? Repeat values?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear, I meant like when I tested this code with sublists that had a length of 3 then it worked correctly, but when I tested it with code that had sublists with a length of 2 then it returns the IndexError

Comment: I tested my code with `print(str(interleave([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 0]])))` and I get the correct result `[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8, 0]`, what am I missing?

Comment: I'm sorry, you were completely right, I had one character out of place. Thank you for the help. Really much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix to your function

```
def interleave(nums):
    new_nums = []
    index = 0
    if len(nums) == 0:
        return new_nums
    for j in range(len(nums)):
        for i in range(len(nums[0])):
            new_nums.append(nums[i][index])
        index += 1
    return new_nums


print("Testing interleave() for nums = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]: " + str(
    interleave([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])))
```

You can use j instead of the index - no need for index

Basically, what you want to do is transpose the two dimentional array and ravel (concat)
See below the last line using numpy

```
import numpy as np
def interleave(nums):
    new_nums = []
    if len(nums) == 0:
        return new_nums
    for j in range(len(nums)):
        for i in range(len(nums[0])):
            new_nums.append(nums[i][j])
    return new_nums


print("Testing interleave() for nums = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]: " + str(
    interleave([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])))

print ("Testing interleave() for nums = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]: ", list(np.ravel(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]).transpose())))
```

Comment: For some reason I still get a IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I updated the answer. I ran the code and I get no issues with the code in the answer. I also suggested the use of transpose and ravel

Comment: Sorry for bothering again but I tested it with two more sets of values and I still get an IndexError, is it because the Sublists are different lengths? Also thanks for taking the time to look at this.

Comment: not sure why! Try this one line (the last line) in python command line `print ("Testing interleave() for nums = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]: ", list(np.ravel(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]).transpose())))`